# SQL how to calculate average with grouping of rows

Tags: sql

Suppose I have this table:

| Name | Marks | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | Maths |
| B | 8 | English |
| A | 6 | English |
| B | 8 | Maths |
| C | 2 | Chemistry |

Now I want to find, for which names is average Maths score greater than average English score?

I have tried running this query

```
SELECT name FROM "xyz_table" 
GROUP BY name
HAVING (SELECT avg(marks) FROM "xyz_table" where Subject = 'Maths' GROUP BY subject) < (SELECT avg(conv_price(price)) FROM "xyz_table" where subject = 'English' GROUP BY subject)
```

Can you please help, I am a newbie to SQL and am stuck on this query.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: This site's purpose is not to explain how SQL works and to provide an entire solution for beginners. The idea is to help people who encounter a specific issue with their code. So you should please show what you have tried, explain what didn't work as expected and what exactly you need to know. Otherwise, you will do better to read some tutorials and documentations about SQL functions.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute I'll add the query that I have created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY Name
HAVING AVG(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) >
       AVG(CASE WHEN Subject = 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END);
```

SELECT Name: We select the "Name" column to get the names of the students.

FROM your_table_name: Replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table.

GROUP BY Name: We group the rows by the "Name" column to calculate averages for each student separately.

HAVING AVG(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) > AVG(CASE WHEN Subject = 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END):

This part does the comparison. It calculate the average marks for "Maths" and "English" separately using conditional aggregation. If the average Maths score is greater than the average English score for a student, their name will be included in the result.

Comment: Thank you Neo for your quick reply, I was making the query overcomplicated by adding the sub-queries. Thank you so much for your quick reply.